# Redis-cli doesn’t work if I plug in a lan cable,but works If I'm on wifi

Tags: redis, client

Basically I'm connecting to a redis server with 
`redis-cli -h adress -p port` and if I'm on wifi I can connect but if I'm on LAN it gives me this error: `Could not connect to redis at localhost port Connection refused`.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: the `IP` address for LANand WIFI are different, are you sure you are using a long address? you can verify using `ifconfig`  command

Comment: Didn’t find  a solution still but I used Redsmin and it works ,so basically solved my problem in a different way .Thanks for the comment !